# How to properly handle the expiration date of a JWT with Yesod?

Tags: haskell, jwt, yesod

I am currently developing a web server using the Yesod framework for a course project. I am new to Haskell and I am fascinated by how different it is to everything else I know regarding programming languages. However, it is not all roses. Sometimes I get stuck for days, and this question is about one such case.

These are the functions that validate the bearer tokens that come with the requests:

```
isDateExpired :: Maybe JWT.NumericDate -> Maybe JWT.NumericDate -> IO (Maybe Bool)
isDateExpired exptime currtime = return $ (<) <$> exptime <*> currtime

validateToken :: Handler AuthResult
validateToken = do
    bearerToken <- lookupBearerAuth
    master <- getYesod
    when (isNothing bearerToken) $ permissionDenied "Token not present in headers."
    let decodedAndVerified  = join $ JWT.decodeAndVerifySignature (JWT.secret (clientSecret master)) <$> bearerToken
        claimset            = JWT.claims <$> decodedAndVerified
        audience            = join $ JWT.aud <$> claimset
        iss = join $ JWT.iss <$> claimset
        expiration = join $ JWT.exp <$> claimset
    case audience of
        Just a -> do
            case a of
                Left uniqueAud -> do 
                    when (Just uniqueAud /= JWT.stringOrURI (clientId master)) $ permissionDenied "Invalid aud."
                Right _ -> permissionDenied "Tokens with multiple aud values not currently supported."
        _ -> permissionDenied "Audience not defined."
    when (iss /= JWT.stringOrURI (configIssuer master)) $
        permissionDenied "Invalid issuer."
    when (isNothing claimset) $
        permissionDenied "Claimset invalid."
    let mExpired = JWT.numericDate <$> getPOSIXTime >>= isDateExpired expiration
    --FIXME Currently, this next part has to be at the end of the function.
    liftIO $ mExpired >>= 
        \y -> if isNothing y then return $ Unauthorized "Expiration date missing." 
            else if y==Just True then return $ Unauthorized "Invalid expiration date."
                else return $ Authorized
```

Well, this code actually works. It correctly validates the tokens. However, as you can see with the FIXME there, the last part of the `validateToken` function is very hacky. It necessarily has to be the last line, and that annoys me.

From what I have gathered, the proper way to handle this would be to use `when` just like it's done in the cases above it. The problem, that I hope someone here can shed some light on, is that when validating the expiration date I end up with an `IO (Maybe Bool)` in that `mExpired` variable. And `when` doesn't accept that.

What I wanted to do was (in pseudo-Haskell) something like this:

```
when (isNothing mExpired || mExpired == Just True) $ permissionDenied "Invalid expiration date."
```

And then I could check other things after that, and at the end of the function put `Authorized` and all is correct and beautiful.

Is something like that at all possible?

FYI: `permissionDenied`'s type is `Failure ErrorResponse m => String -> m a`

Comment: Side note: in your use case, `currtime` in `isDateExpired` being `Nothing` means there was a parse failure in `JWT.numericDate`, and you end up merging this case with the expiration-date-missing failure. In this case it doesn't really matter (as far as I can tell, `getPOSIXTime` can't produce an invalid date for this purpose), but it's good to be attentive to situations like this, in which something might slip through the cracks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a second look at `isDateExpired`:

```
isDateExpired :: Maybe JWT.NumericDate -> Maybe JWT.NumericDate -> IO (Maybe Bool)
isDateExpired exptime currtime = return $ (<) <$> exptime <*> currtime
```

This is actually a pure function: `(<$>)` and `(<*>)` here are those of the `Maybe` functor, and the result is in `IO` merely because of the `return` at the end. So let's get rid of it:

```
isDateExpired :: Maybe JWT.NumericDate -> Maybe JWT.NumericDate -> Maybe Bool
isDateExpired exptime currtime = (<) <$> exptime <*> currtime
```

This clears our view quite a bit; we can deal with how to get that into `IO` as a separate step.

Given that `isDateExpired` is now a pure function, we don't need the `(>>=)` in `mExpired` any longer:

```
    let mExpired = isDateExpired expiration . JWT.numericDate <$> getPOSIXTime
```

`mExpired` is still an `IO (Maybe Bool)`, thanks to `getPOSIXTime`. We can change that by using `<-` (and `liftIO`) rather than `let`:

```
    mExpired <- liftIO $ isDateExpired expiration . JWT.numericDate <$> getPOSIXTime
```

(Note that you had done almost the same thing. I brought the `liftIO` together with the rest of it so that I don't have to think of a redundant name for the `IO (Maybe Bool)` intermediate value, which is for the most part uninteresting.)

The most straightforward way to decide what to do next is pattern matching on `mExpired`:

```
    case mExpired of
        Nothing -> permissionDenied "Expiration date missing."
        Just expired -> when expired $ permissionDenied "Invalid expiration date."
```

Pattern matching tends to be more comfortable to use than boolean tests, except perhaps when you already have a `Bool` in your hands. (A corollary is that there usually is a nicer alternative to using `isJust` and `isNothing` -- though I feel the your uses of `isNothing` with `when` elsewhere in the do-block are fine.)

---

The refactoring just above assumes you want to distinguish the missing date case from the invalid date one. Though I suspect that is actually what you want/need, let's assume for a moment that you'd rather disregard the difference (and thus handle `Nothing` and `Just False` in the same way). `fromMaybe` from `Data.Maybe` allows you to do that in a very convenient way:

```
fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a
```

```
    when (fromMaybe True mExpired) $ permissionDenied "Invalid expiration date."
```

This amounts to your "pseudo-Haskell" line -- in effect, we are supplying `True` as a default value for `mExpired`. If you were to go down that route, you might even move the `fromMaybe True` to `isExpired`, so that it would result in a `Bool` to begin with.

Another function worth mentioning is `maybe`, which amounts to case analysis on `Maybe` packaged into a function:

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

Using it, the case-statement I wrote a few lines above could be replaced with:

```
    -- Line breaks added for clarity.
    maybe
        (permissionDenied "Expiration date missing.")
        (\expired -> when expired $ permissionDenied "Invalid expiration date.")
        mExpired
```

While this is, in this case, arguably less readable than the case-statement, `maybe` is a function that you can compose, partially apply, etc.; which can be taken advantage of in other circumstances.

(A tiny puzzle: what does `(>>=)` for `Maybe` look like if you use `maybe` to define it?)

Comment: What a fascinating language! Thanks a lot for the answer. I'm still struggling with the whole concept of monads and such, but that just makes learning it more fun!

The one thing that I couldn't understand in your answer was how `let mExpired = isDateExpired expiration . JWT.numericDate <$> getPOSIXTime` works. If the current time is wrapped in IO, how can it be passed as an argument to isDateExpired?

About your puzzle, my guess would be: `maybe (Nothing) (\v -> ...) (k)`. Was I close?

Comment: @LéoVital (1) `(.)` has higher precedence than `(<$>)`, so that amounts to `(isDateExpired expiration . JWT.numericDate) <$> getPOSIXTime` (that is, we're `fmap`ping the `isDateExpired expiration` as well. (2) Yup, that is spot on. By the way, that would look even nicer in terms of `(=<<)` (bind with flipped arguments) -- `(=<<) = maybe Nothing`.